# The evaluation process of a compound expression containing two assignment operators in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, assignment-operator, ecmascript-5, operator-precedence, associativity

Here is a compound expression containing two assignment operators:

```
var a = {n: 1};
var b = a;
a.x = a = {m: 2};
a;    // => {m: 2}
b;    // => {n: 1, x: {m: 2}}
```

The tricky part is the third line:

```
a.x = a = {m: 2};
```

IMHO, The assignment operator `=` is right-associative, so the nesting structure of the expression is:

```
a.x = (a = {m: 2});
```

But the evaluation order in ES5 is always from left to right, according to [ES5 Annex D](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-D).

According to [ES5 Section 11.13.1](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.1),

> The production *AssignmentExpression* : *LeftHandSideExpression* =
>   *AssignmentExpression* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let *lref* be the result of evaluating *LeftHandSideExpression*.
> 2. Let *rref* be the result of evaluating *AssignmentExpression*.
> 3. Let *rval* be GetValue(*rref*).
> 4. Throw a **SyntaxError** exception if the following conditions are all true: 
>      ....**omitted intentionally to save space**
> 5. PutValue(*lref*, *rval*).
> 6. Return *rval*.

So my understanding of the left-to-right evaluation order is :

1. evaluate `a.x` first and return a reference `lref1` for it
2. evaluate `a = {m: 2}` to obtain `rref1`, because it is also an assignment expression, we'll start the procedure again (like recursion)

   2.1. evaluate `a` first and return a reference `lref2` for it

   2.2. evaluate `{m: 2}` and return the very object `{m: 2}` as `rref2`

   2.3. Let `rval2` = `GetValue(rref2)`, so `rval2` is also the object `{m: 2}`

   2.4. `PutValue(lref2, rval2)`, so `a` will rebinds the object `{m: 2}` instead of `{n: 1}`

   2.5. return `rval2`, i.e. the object `{m: 2}` as `rref1` (not Reference type, but object)
3. Let `rval1` = `GetValue(rref1)`, which is also the very object `{m: 2}`
4. `PutValue(lref1, rval1)`, so the memory address which `lref1` refers to will be `{m: 2}`. And `b.x` still refers to this address and `b` will be updated.

This procedure complies to the ES5 Spec and explains the result well.

My questions are:

1. Is this evaluation order abovementioned true or false? If false, any alternative explanations?
2. How to understand the Reference Specification Type in ES5 appropriately? Is it just an intermediate pointer which refers to certain memory address?

Comment: I'm not sure I get it, assigning a new value to `a` after `b = a` doesn't change `b`, changing `b` only happens if you change the properties of `a` ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/engvqu24/

Comment: Hi @adeneo, `b` is actually updated after the `a.x = a = {m:2}` expression, you can test it in console.

Comment: @adeneo pls note in the expression `a.x = a = {m: 2}`, both the rebinding and mutation of `a` occurred, so the evaluation order matters!

Comment: That's because `a.x = expression` is evaluated first, it's set to whatever the next expression returns, and an assignment always returns the assigned value, which is `{m: 2}`, so you get `b.x` before `a` is overwritten, is that what you're asking ?

Comment: @adeneo Yes, I'm asking for the confirmation of evaluation order. Actually, we get `b.x` updated (Procedure 4) after `a` is overwritten (Procedure 2.4).

Comment: See also [Multiple assignment confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34025695/multiple-assignment-confusion) and [Javascript code trick: What's the value of `foo.x`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32342809/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your understanding about the operator order appears to be correct.

[ECMAScript 5 section 8.7](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7) says:

> A Reference consists of three components, the **base value**, the **referenced name** and the Boolean valued strict reference flag. The base value is either undefined, an Object, a Boolean, a String, a Number, or an environment record (10.2.1).

The process of creating a reference from property access is defined in [11.2.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.1):

> 8. Return a value of type Reference whose base value is *baseValue* and whose referenced name is *propertyNameString*, and whose strict mode flag is *strict*.

Thus the reference `lref1` holds the *object value* of `a` (along with the referenced name string `"x"`), which you originally created with `{n: 1}`. A reference does not care about the *variable* that it came from; it cares only about what *base value* and *reference name* it is supplied when created.

**Altering what value is held by `a` has no effect whatsoever on the base value held by the reference `lref1`**. `lref1` continues to the hold the original value of `a` (i.e., that `{n: 1}` object) regardless of what `a` does after the creation of `lref1`.

In short, the reference created from the expression `a.x` ceases to have anything to do with the variable `a` as soon as the reference is created. Instead, the reference knows only about the value that was held by `a` at the time the reference was created.

Comment: you mean `lref1` holds the reference of `a.x`, right? The base value of `lref1` should be `a`, the referenced name should be `"x"`. But pls not `a` doesn't has a `x` property, so it must create a `x` property here?

Comment: @LeslieZhang The base value of `lref1` should be the *value of `a`*, yes. Again, the reference has nothing more to do with the identifier or variable `a` after the reference is created. It only has a value (whatever was in `a` at the reference's creation time) and a reference name (`"x"`). /// The creation of the `x` property is handled by the [`PutValue`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7.2) required by step 5 of the assignment steps.

Comment: `It only has a value (whatever was in a at the reference's creation time) and a reference name ("x").` At the reference creation time, the value should be `undefined`. Because at creation time, `a === {n: 1}`, if we access `a.x`, we get `undefined`.

Comment: @LeslieZhang Note that I said, "whatever was in `a` at the reference's creation time" not "whatever was in `a.x` at the reference's creation time". A reference has two parts, called "base value" and "referenced name". The reference's base value here is the *initial value of `a`*, not `a.x`. The `x` component is stored separately, as a string, in the reference's "referenced name" component. The `PutValue` operation, in step 5 of assignment, is when we store a value in the `x` property of the base value held by the reference.

Comment: @ apsillers That's what confused me, the reference type