# JavaScript code trick: What's the value of foo.x

Tags: javascript, object, variable-assignment

I found this problem in a GitHub front-end interview questions collection:

> ```
> var foo = {n: 1};
> var bar = foo;
> foo.x = foo = {n: 2};
> ```
>
> Question: What is the value of foo.x?

The answer is `undefined`.

I've done some research and what I understand this problem is (correct me if I'm wrong):

- `var foo = {n: 1};` declares an object `foo` which has property `n` equal to 1.
- `var bar = foo;` declares an object `bar` which refers to the same object as `foo`.
- `foo.x = foo = {n: 2};` which I believe is equal to `foo.x = (foo = {n: 2});`
- And then I got `foo.x` equals to `undefined`. However, the value of `bar.x` is the object `{n:2}`.

If `bar` and `foo` refer to same object, why did `bar.x` get a value while `foo.x` is `undefined`? What is really happening in `foo.x = foo = {n: 2};`?

Comment: And questions like that on an interview are horrible...

Comment: I'd consider that a bug in the parser. because the second assignment should evaluate first. meaning `foo.x` should be a reference to `foo`. JavaScript objects are passed by reference so, in theory, bar should be equal to foo

Comment: @epascarello can't agree more..

Comment: @self yeah maybe.. we need to figure out how the interpreter works..

Comment: the value of `bar.x` is the first object, `{n:1}`

Comment: the problem is why `foo != {n: 2, x: {n:2}}` , while bar.x = {n: 1, x: {n: 2}}?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
foo.x = foo = {n: 2};
```

determines that `foo.x` refers to a property `x` of the `{n: 1}` object, assigns `{n: 2}` to `foo`, and assigns the new value of `foo` – `{n: 2}` – to the property `x` of the `{n: 1}` object.

The important thing is that the `foo` that `foo.x` refers to is determined before `foo` changes.

See [section 11.13.1 of the ES5 spec](https://es5.github.io/#x11.13.1):

> 1. Let *lref* be the result of evaluating *LeftHandSideExpression*.
> 2. Let *rref* be the result of evaluating *AssignmentExpression*.

The assignment operator associates right to left, so you get:

```
foo.x = (foo = {n: 2})
```

The left hand side is evaluated before the right hand side.

Comment: Is the reference resolution order mandated by some standard or is it just how particular implementation does it?

Comment: @soulcheck: It is mandated by the standard. Finding important parts now. (It’s also somewhat mandated by common sense – consider `(x = {}).y = x`)

Comment: @soulcheck Thanks. And so do you mean that `foo` is `{n:2}` now after assignment, but `foo.x` belong to the old 'foo = {n:1}' object which is not exist anymore because `foo` has been changed to `{n:2}` And thus `foo.x` fail to be assigned the value but `bar.x` got the value because `bar` always exist and never been changed? Oh my...

Comment: @AndyHu: `foo.x` refers to the `x` of the old `foo`. `bar` also refers to the old `foo`. `x` does not exist on the new `foo`.

Comment: @minitech Ok I got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 25):

```
foo.x = foo = {n: 2};
```

Here `foo` refers to `{n:1}` object before assignment i.e. before the statement is executed.

The statement can be re-written as `foo.x = (foo = {n:2});`

In object terms the above statement can be re-written as
`{n:1}.x = ( {n:1} = {n:2} );`

Since assignment happens from right to left only. So here we just have to keep a check that `foo` is referring to which object before execution starts.

On solving the R.H.S:  `foo = {n:2};` Now `foo` is referring to `{n:2};`

Coming back on the problem we are left with:

```
foo.x = foo;
```

Now `foo.x` on L.H.S  is still `{n:1}.x` whereas `foo` on R.H.S is `{n:2}`.

So after this statement gets executed `{n:1}` will become `{ n:1, x:{n:2} }` with bar still referring to it.
Where as `foo` will now be referring to `{n:2}`.

So on execution `foo.x` gives `undefined` as there is only 1 value in `foo` which is `{n:2}`.

But if you will try executing `bar.x` it will give `{n:2}`.
Or if you will just execute `bar` the result will be

```
Object {n: 1, x: Object}
```

Answer (score 12):

As I  understand expression :

```
foo.x = foo = {n: 2};
```

just exactly the same as:

```
foo.x = {n: 2} ; 
foo = {n: 2};
```

And after this it's became obvious that:

```
 bar=={n: 1, x: {n:2}};
 foo=={n:2};
 foo.x==undefined
```

Answer (score 4):

I thought I'd add another, what I found to be, helpful way of thinking about this.

Those last variable assignments are equivalent to writing `bar.x = foo = {n:2};`, because those variables are just references to the same thing in memory.

In other words, `foo` and `bar` are, at first, both referencing the same object, `{n:1}`. When you use `foo.x =`, you are accessing `{n:1}` and adding the `x` property to it. This could be done with either `bar` or `foo` because they both point to that same object in memory! It makes no difference.

Then when you complete that line, `foo.x = foo = {n:2}`, you are creating another, *brand new*, object in memory via object literal syntax and setting `foo` to point to *that* object, `{n:2}`, instead of what is now `{n:1, x: {n: 2}`. This doesn't affect what `foo` pointed to when you added the `x` property to it, though.

This is pretty confusing, but I think makes sense you think about the fact that variables are just pointers to places/objects in memory, and that object literal syntax isn't changing the previously existing object (even though they look similar). It's creating a brand new one.

The beginning of accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value) may be helpful as well.

Comment: This is helpful! The key for me was realizing that `bar` becomes `{n: 1, x: {n: 2}}` and `foo` becomes `{n: 2}`. That is why the problem introduces the `bar` variable.

Answer (score 4):

It is a matter of understanding that object variables are merely references  to the objects in JavaScript and not objects themselves.

`var foo = {n: 1}` -> foo refers to the real object {n: 1}
`var bar = foo` -> bar is now also a reference to the real object {n: 1}

The tricky part is of course the 3rd line:
`foo.x = foo = {n: 2}`

This is equivalent to:
`(reference to {n: 1}).x = (foo = {n: 2})` -> after this line is completely evaluated, foo becomes a reference to the new object {n: 2}; however, since foo refers to the original object `{n: 1}` prior to the evaluation of the line, the original object `{n: 1}` becomes `{n: 1, x: [reference to]{n: 2}}` after the line is evaluated, and the modified object will be accessible through the reference `bar`. If there was no reference bar, the original object would be destroyed

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to understand this is using references.

When `var foo = {n: 1};` executes, let's say memory gets allocated to this object at location `A`. So, foo is currently pointing to `A`.

When `var bar = foo;` executes and `bar` refers to the same location `A`.

When `foo.x = foo = {n: 2};` executes, firstly referencing will take place and then the assignment will happen from right to left.

One can visualize it like this:

Another memory location will be created for {n: 2}, say 'B'

`(object at A).x = foo = (object at B);`

Step1: the assignment will start from right to left, so `foo` will point to `B` location.

Step 2: the object at `A` (i.e. `{n: 1}`) will have another property `x` with value `foo` (`{n: 2}`); `bar` still points to `A` memory location, so it will have this value.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEnTz.png)

Answer (score -1):

i think in Javascript you cant assign a value to a property which doesn't exist if the object isn't empty. so in this case foo object has a property and value pair which is {n:1} so since it isn't empty and it doesn't have a x property ,you cant assign but since you assign bar object a value which is foo object ,it will have the value whatever the foo is