# Assigning object literal property to the object itself, maybe

Tags: javascript, properties, object-literal

I found this question in the [`h5bp/Front-end-Developer-Interview-Questions`](https://github.com/h5bp/Front-end-Developer-Interview-Questions#coding-questions) repository.

One example confused me.

```
var foo = {n: 1};
var bar = foo;
foo.x = foo = {n: 2};
// foo.x is undefined  /* WHY??? */
bar.y = bar;  // This works however.
bar.y.y.y;
//> Object {n: 1, x: Object, y: Object}
var xoxo = foo = {n: 2};
//> Object {n: 2}
```

With `bar`, I assigned the object literal's `x` property to the object itself and what appears to be happening now, is that it's referencing itself through `x` "infinite times".

I expected the same behaviour from the line `foo.x = foo = {n: 2};`. What happens with `foo.x` and why? If you explained the steps that will get me to the right answer, I'd appreciate it

Wanted to see if there is a flaw in my right-hand assignment logic, but `xoxo` seems to be assigned as I expected.

Comment: Strange! I always believed javascript did right hand assignment a = (b = (c = 1)). I want to know the reason too.

Comment: Haha, I, too, was thinking along the lines of right-hand assignment, but it's clearly not what happens

Comment: I believe it does happen, but something's goofy with objects

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342809/javascript-code-trick-whats-the-value-of-foo-x

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript code trick :What's the value of foo.x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342809/javascript-code-trick-whats-the-value-of-foo-x)

Comment: The mechanism behind this is very well described in Chapter 1 "What is scope ?" of Kyle Simpson's book "Scope & Closures" from the "You Don't Know Js" book series

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for the question as I suspected it would cause headache for other people, too, but I didn't find it.