# What does x => x mean when passed to a function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecma

Say I have code like this:

```
function Foo(func) 
{
    var a = new SomeClass(func(5));
}
var b = new Foo(x=>x);
```

What does the x => x mean in the parameter? x is not defined anywhere else.

Comment: Its the function passed as an argument. The function accepts the parameter `x` and returns it back. Also if `x` is not declared(its value can be `undefined`) anywhere there will be a runtime exception.

Comment: Foo() doesn't return anything, and x doesn't appear anywhere else in the script and yet the code executes correctly.

Comment: Not my solution but the answer is given in the below link [Javascript code trick :What's the value of foo.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342809/javascript-code-trick-whats-the-value-of-foo-x)

Comment: This is called "arrow functions". Read more about it here: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arrow-function-definitions

Answer (score 2):

It is the arrow notation,

```
x=>x
```

implies function which takes one parameter and returns back the same parameter.

It is the same as:-

```
function test(x) {
  return x;
}
var b = new Foo(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Hozefa said, the function accepts the parameter `x` and returns it back.

Basically:

```
const func = x => x
```

means:

```
const func = function (x) {
    return x
}
```

It's an ES6 Syntax which you learn more here: http://es6-features.org/